# Python - Make socket server on Public Internet Protocol

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, network-protocols

On Python I would like to make a python server on my public IP...

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(("Public IP", 80))
s.listen(5)
conn, addr = s.accept()
```

But once it hits the bind command

```
error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

How would I fix this, how would I get other people around the globe to connect to my python server.

Comment: Are you running this code as root? Port 80 is privileged and one requires super-user access to bind to it. What happens when you run the same code on a port number > 1024? Why don't you try `s.bind(('', 80))`? That will make your program accept connections form _everywhere_

Comment: Please be more precise about what you mean by "Public IP"?

Comment: The IP is from http://www.whatismyip.com/, which is a public IP, and I can connect to it through python sockets on port 80.

Comment: So you are behind a NAT? You would need to configure your NAT to let port 80 through to your PC's IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only bind to an address that's configured on an interface on your local machine. Since you're using the phrase "public IP", I'm assuming that your public IP is only configured on your router, and your computer has a private address on your local network.

Have your program bind to the machine's local IP, or to any IP available (e.g, `("", 80)`), then configure port forwarding on your router appropriately.

Comment: Yes thank you. When I mean public IP, I mean the IP you use to connect to websites and websites record. http://supportcenter.verio.com/KB/questions.php?questionid=655